# How do I simplify this

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am attempting to write a code that is applied to old files stored on my hard drive. I have written the code and it works but it rather long and as sections repeat itself it could use some simplifying.

Because the old files change slightly the location of the sum may change which is why I use variables for row references. the code in question is

```
ws1.Cells(n + first, 52).Formula = "=" & Split(Cells(1, 52).Address, "$")(1) & n + first - 1 & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 5).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 8).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 11).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 14).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 17).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 20).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 23).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 26).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 29).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 32).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 35).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 38).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 41).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 44).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 47).Address, "$")(1) & n + first
```

As you can see the split is repeated changing by 3 columns each time.

The point of the code is a simply cell(x,y) = cell(x-1,y) + sum....

I believe it would be possible to pass it through a for loop that returns a string that is concatenated?

note: this is in a for loop running through values of n. First is a variable to identify the start of the calculations

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily using the split to get address. You could use `Cells(n,m).Address(False, False) instead of`Split(Cells(1, m).Address, "$")(1) & n `

then use string concat to get the whole formula,

```vb
stri = "=" & Cells(52,n + first - 1).Address(False, False)
i=5
Do While i < 48 
   stri = stri & "+" & Cells(i,n + first).Address(False, False)
   i=i+3
Loop
ws1.Cells(n + first, 52).Formula = stri
```

Comment: I don't have excel with me to test, test it and tell me if it works, or what it outputs..